# Why I'm getting "maximum recursion depth exceeded"

Tags: python, if-statement, recursion

I just saw an alternative construction for python's `if-else` statements like `(0, 1)[ x > 5]` and wanted to try it with recursion but for some reason it's not working. Just forget for a moment that it's unpythonic.

Here is an original code which I'm trying to replace with alternative:

```
def f(n):
    return 1 if n == 1 else n * f(n - 1)
```

Alternative, which give recursion problem:

```
def f(n):
    return (n * f(n - 1), 1)[n == 1]
```

What is the problem with alternative code?

Comment: You might try to debug the problem yourself by inserting `print n` inside the body of the alternative function.

Comment: ask yourself "what happens when n==1?" Does the function stop calling itself, or does it continue? What will cause it to stop?

Comment: @BryanOakley I assume that expression will evaluate to True, which will cast to 1 and return second element of tuple, what will stop recursion.

Comment: Because your condition is after your tuple which is contain the function itself and there for calling it recursively for until it encounter the `RuntimeError`.

Comment: First syntax uses short-circuiting, second does not. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator

Comment: re: _"I assume that expression will evaluate to True"_: don't _assume_. You need to know for certain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that Python will always try to compute `n * f(n - 1)` before indexing the tuple with `[n == 1]`.

The result is that the function keeps calling itself until the process runs out of memory on the stack.

The first code avoids this by doing the `n==1` check before the recursive call, and then not making the call if the check succeeds

Source:

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html has a section on 'Evaluation order' stating that it is performed left to right.

Answer (score 2):

Your first function short circuits. `n * f(n - 1)` is *only* computed if `n != 1`.

In the second function, Python must evaluate both elements to create the `list`, so `n * f(n - 1)` is *always* computed, even when the elements are never accessed. This results in infinite recursion.